# Cant Join Meshes ("Visible Mesh" with "Non-Visible" Mesh)

Tags: modeling, mesh, object-mode, svg, remesh

What I have done:

-I Have turned a SVG file into a Mesh hence the "First 5 Engraved Commands"

-I Added a boolean to the "Stone Tablet" Mesh to get the "engraved" look you see by making the "First 5 Engraved Commands" non-visible - (In the viewport and In rendered)

(Common method used for "carving pumpkins in blender")

What I already tried to do:

- I tried to used Ctrl-J to join and tried selecting them in different orders to change the parent object.
- To kill myself...jk I love blender and modeling. But need help because Im pretty sure they do not offer this option or have not yet added it because blender is still being built. If thats the case let me know... If not help me.

What I want to do:

-I want to join the "First 5 Engraved Commands" Mesh with the "Stone Tablet" Mesh together and I am unable to do so and not sure why. I want it to be a single object.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you make it visible? Also, joining them will destroy you boolean... Why do you want to join them?

Comment: I used this method in creating a pumpkin - Watch this part for how I did it... This is for the questions reference:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_mIiUoPr-s&t=1567s    check at 25:07 on the video to see what I did with the stone tablet as well.

Comment: @Psyonic - It just ends up looking like the first photo I posted in the Forum... And than I can join them together to be able to export the object for animations and stuff thats why I wanna join them... But I want it engraved not like the first photo... it beats the purpose of the engraving.

Comment: If you want to export your mesh so it's like your 2nd pic, just apply the boolean first.

Comment: (✅ Issue Fixed : If you want to export your mesh so it's like your 2nd pic, just apply the Boolean first.)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                               You fixed it Thank you @Psyonic so simple but it works and I'm grateful you are alive for it. I forgot I can apply the effect sometimes our brains need a quick break